# Raspberry pi zero arduboy

Tags: pi-zero, pygame, games

I saw the arduboy some time ago and got quite interested in it. I'd like to know if it is possible, through some kind of os, to make something of the sort with a raspberry pi zero w(make my own games on a PC and load them up). Also, is it possible to upload a few pi games as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk/) and modify a GameBoy cartridge as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZ5J.jpg) to run games with an RPi zero and carry it along with you. The project was featured on the Raspberry Pi Foundation's [blog](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/game-boy-zero/).

Here's a video showing the [build process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvSEcGcppqc).

Comment: I was trying to make my own games like an Arduino. The reason I'm not using an Arduino is because I wanted to make games in Python or JS and upload the files

Comment: I could use buildroot to make something to suit my needs but I'm still open to suggestions